# Google Ads Scripts: How to get 30 days of data, then loop on each day of it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

My problem is I want to get the last 30 days of data, then loop through it to get each day's data. if it's possible to loop through it.

I know how to add data, to a Google spreadsheet.
I know how to get the last 30 days of data.

The thing is even if I grab the LAST_30_DAYS of data it is in bulk as I far as I know, and not sure how to segment that data by date or if it's possible.

Here's the full code.

```
function main() {

  var mql = "MQL";
  var report = AdsApp.report('SELECT Conversions, Date ' + 
                             'FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' + 
                             'WHERE ConversionTypeName CONTAINS "'+mql+'" ' +
                             'DURING YESTERDAY ');

  var cost_data = AdsApp.report('SELECT Cost, Date ' +
                                 'FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
                                 'DURING YESTERDAY ');
  var cost_rows = cost_data.rows();
  var cost_row = cost_rows.next();
  var cost_string = JSON.stringify(cost_row);
  var cost_json = JSON.parse(cost_string);
  var rows = report.rows();
  if(rows.hasNext()){
    var row = rows.next();
    var row_string = JSON.stringify(row);
    var row_json = JSON.parse(row_string);
    appendARow(cost_json.Date, row_json.Conversions, cost_json.Cost);
  } else {
    appendARow(cost_json.Date, 0, cost_json.Cost);
  }

}

function appendARow(date, conversion, cost) {
    var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'URL';

    var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1';

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    sheet.appendRow([date, conversion, cost])
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any code to help solve the problem?

Comment: Does each record have a date posted?

Comment: If you have the data in a spreadsheet, can you share it, or a sanitized exampled so it's easier to understand how to help? The way to proceed for you would probably be to have a script that runs on a monthly trigger to check the last 30 entries of that data. you can have a daily script to get the data to the sheet, and a monthly one to check the data itself.

Comment: @ross here's the code to get the last 30 days of data.
AdsApp.report('SELECT Cost, Date ' +
                                 'FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
                                 'DURING LAST_30_Days ');

The problem with that is it grabs the bulk data, not sure how to segment it by date.

Comment: @AlbertoMolina, my spreadsheet has the following columns "Date", "MQLs(conversion action)", "Cost". I just added the code on my question. Feel free to check it out.

Comment: @EinsteinVillamor Change your time parameter in the query to `DURING LAST_30_DAYS` and instead of using the `appendARow()` method you created, declare the ss spreadsheet in your main method and then use `exportToSheet(sheet)` method to put the information in the sheet directly. [Here is some documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/reference/adsapp/adsapp_report#exportToSheet_1) on how to use the method.

Comment: @AlbertoMolina but I want it segmented by day, so if I grab LAST_30_DAYS, then exportToSheet(sheet), Would I see 30 entries/row on my spreadsheet?

Comment: @EinsteinVillamor  believe it would, since you have everything set up, could you try it out?

Comment: @AlbertoMolina Thanks! dude, it's working now.

Comment: Happy to help! I'm going to be posting the answer for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Posting for documentation.

Change your time parameter in the query to `DURING LAST_30_DAYS` and instead of using the `appendARow()` method you created, declare the `ss` spreadsheet in your main method and then use `exportToSheet(sheet)` method to put the information in the sheet directly.

[Here is some documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/reference/adsapp/adsapp_report#exportToSheet_1) on how to use the method.